# Use fitdistrplus package to fit an exponential distribution with error code 100

Tags: exp, fitdistrplus

I'm fitting an Exponential distribution using Fitdistcens function from distrplus package. my dataset contain complete data and suspension data. however, "exp" give me an error message below:

```
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobjcens, fix.arg = fix.arg, 
gr = gradient, 
rcens = rcens, lcens = lcens, icens = icens, ncens = ncens, 
ddistnam = ddistname, pdistnam = pdistname, hessian = TRUE, 
method = meth, lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): non-finite finite- 
difference value [1]>

Error in fitdistcens(dataset1, "exp") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
        with the error code 100
```

here are my code:

```
dataset1<-dataset[1:2]

library(fitdistrplus)

fitexp <- fitdistcens(dataset1,"exp")
```

can somebody help me resolve this error code? i can share my dataset.